# Is there a something similar to DSLR batteries to power up PCBs?

Tags: batteries, pcb, pcb-design, connector

I'm working on a project that requires the user to regularly swap battery packs to keep an esp32 board running. For the prototype we are using one of these batteries that seem to be quite common to find:

[image: Li-ion battery]

Swapping this kind of battery is not a smooth process, and I think the connector might not be meant for regular mating.

Are there any batteries similar to those of DSLRs? or any other good alternatives?

I recently came across [Duracell selling battery replacements](https://www.duracelldirect.co.uk/digital-camera/sony/a7-battery--j5f6ft.html) for common DSLRs, the problem is that I'm finding it hard to find the terminals for these batteries so that we can add them to the final design of the PCB.

I'm aware that voltage and power wise these will vary a lot. I'm primarily asking for PCB components similar to those found in DSLR that can be bought commercially.

Comment: You're right JST connectors like that are meant for assembly, not to be swapped in and out regularly. It can be done, especially if using some kind of pliers to pull on the shell, not the wires - but there is a tendency for users to pull directly on the wires which can lead to them breaking.

Comment: Note that what you have here is not a PCB component; it's a battery with wires and a connector. The matching connector is a PCB component that sits on the PCB. Also note that wherever you have wires, you can add your own connector.

Comment: Have you looked at using standardized LiIon packages such as 18650, with suitable battery holders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem is that I'm finding it hard to find the terminals for these batteries so that we can add them to the final design of the PCB.

Consider instead batteries that have flush target pads, such as the ones used in cell phones, for example [these](https://www.razmobility.com/product/minivision2-phone-battery/).

Then, use spring-loaded contacts to mate to the battery (my site):

- [Pogo PCB pins](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=pogo_pins)
- [Pogo PCB header](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=pogo_pin_hdrs)
- [Spring leaf PCB terminals](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=pcb_spring_leaves)
- [Spring leaf PCB header](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=spring_leaf_hdrs)

[image: Pogo pins and flush target]

{This is my picture}

Comment: Note that these require some case design to hold the battery in place; there's no locking mechanism here so they're annoying for prototyping. Not an issue if you consider it, just something noteworthy.